# iPhone duplicate symbol linker error after installing core plot in Xcode 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, core-plot

I've added `libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a` to the project's frameworks and set the header search path to be project-relative an point to the /framework folder and be recursive.

There are no errors visible. WHen I try to build, I get the linker error:

ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTPlot in /Users/alexanderstone/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PDFGenerationDemo-coyoeaupshiotxfbalkrkcmhbkbb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a(CPTPlot.o) and /Users/alexanderstone/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PDFGenerationDemo-coyoeaupshiotxfbalkrkcmhbkbb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a(CPTPlot.o) for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**What am I doing wrong? How can I fix the duplicate symbol error for coreplot install?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core plot in general makes me swear very loudly. Both when I try to install it in a new project, or when I try to use it within the project.

The error above was resolved by renaming the static library include with the project from

```
libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a
```

to

```
libCorePlotCocoaTouch.a
```

Yes, It took me close to 3 hours to resolve this problem.

Comment: Did you include both the Core Plot project file and the static library in your project?